# How to set the height and width of relative layout in percentage

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a certain square space for my `LinearLayout`. Within this `LinearLayout` i have a `RelativeLayout` with height and width `100dp`. This `RelativeLayout` has a circular drawable shape. I want to set the height and width of `RelativeLayout` to be 60% of total space available for its parent `LinearLayout`. Is there a way to do this?

This is the layout which i am designing 
[image]

This is my xml code snippet of one circular view

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_hatchback"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_hatchback_circle"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_red"

                >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_hatchback"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_hatchback_circle"
                    android:text="Hatchback"
                    style="@style/CircularTitle"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you want set in percentage you can use new Constraint layout and set guidelines according to your percentage

Comment: 1. there are many answers for the thing that you want to achieve, so what exactly is the puspose of having that 60% height. 2. your layout is very badly written that can effect your apps performance. 3. once you reply for point#1, i can further help with #1 & #2

Comment: can you please suggest me the best way to represent this layout

Comment: I have created 6 parts within the space available using weights. I want to have that circular layout at the center in each block with the text at its bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PercentRelativeLayout or ConstraintLayout to reduce number of nested views.
For Reference:

**PercentRelativeLayout:** https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

**ConstraintLayout:** 
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html